# Understanding the difference between a static and a non-static method representation on the heap

Tags: java, static, heap-memory, permgen

I have already read some posts on this topic:

- [How are instance methods stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376953/how-are-instance-methods-stored)
- [static allocation in java - heap, stack and permanent generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849634/static-allocation-in-java-heap-stack-and-permanent-generation/3849819#3849819)
- [where is a static method and a static variable stored in java. In heap or in stack memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387989/where-is-a-static-method-and-a-static-variable-stored-in-java-in-heap-or-in-sta)

But I am confused by the concept they illustrate:

> Static methods (in fact all methods) as well as static variables are stored in the PermGen section of the heap, since they are part of the reflection data (class related data, not instance related).

So methods, whether `static` or not, are only stored for one copy on the heap in the class. Now that there is only one copy which is in the class, which I interpreted as all methods belong to the class, then why can Java only call a non-static method using an instantiated instance?

Why do we have the concept that non-static methods belong to the instance, not the class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's another side of the story that needs to be mentioned. When you have a class, say `Bar`:

```
public class Bar {
   public static void doSomething() { ... }

   public void doSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

On the heap the signature for `doSomethingElse` is not `doSomethingElse()` but `doSomethingElse(Bar this)`. As opposed to `doSomething` which is left with no parameters (hence you can't call `this` from a static method - there is no `this` to call to).

When you have a call like this:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.doSomethingElse();
```

It's just a syntactic sugar to:

```
doSomethingElse(bar); // I neglected here for simplification but the name of the method in the compiled code also includes the name of the class.
```

When you define an extending class `Foo`:

```
public class Foo extends Bar {
    @Override
    public void doSomethingElse() { ... }
}
```

Another method is created `doSomethingElse(Foo this)`. Next thing to there is a virtual table (read about it if you're not familiar with the term) - Each class holds a virtual table which maps a method signature to a concrete code. When you call a method in runtime there is a search in the class (not the instance) virtual table for the correct implementation according to the dynamic type of the instance.

So the full example would be (and of course that's just a simplification):

**Java syntax (syntactic sugar):**

```
Bar b = new Foo();
b.doSomethingElse();
```

**What really happens (simplified):**

```
// Step 1: Get the correct overriden method for Foo class from the virtual table
// Step 2: Invoke the method with the instance "b" as the first parameter (the "this" parameter)
Foo.getMethodFromVirtualTable("doSomethingElse").invoke(b);
```

That's only a simplification of course but that's sort of the way it happens.

In fact when you come to think of it, all the methods are static in memory (that's why they reside in `PermGen`). The complier uses the static virtual table for each class in order to call the correct method. This what allows polymorphism.

Comment: thanks god, someone is really reading the question. ty for explenation tho.

Comment: @Avi can you explain when stack and heap memory will get allocated and who allocates this? how is the size of memory determined?

Comment: Heap memory is allocated whenever you call `new` to create an instance of an object. Stack memory contains all primitives (int, char, boolean, etc...) you declare. Also it contains references to 'heap' object (the variable you assign the `new` result to). Memory size is defined by the object your create. The total heap memory can be defined with JVM params (-Xms and -Xmx are the most famous ones) when you start the java app.