# where java store native objects

Tags: java, tomcat, jprofiler

I've been inspecting objects and I noticed that the size of a java.lang.String is always 24 bytes, regardless of the text it contains.

For example:

```
String str1 = "testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest";
String str2 = "test";
```

When computing the Strings' sizes using this method:

```
String test = "hello";
for(int i=0; i<10000; i++){
    test += test + i;
}
log.debug( Agent.inst.getObjectSize( test ) );
```

It tells me that both strings are 24 bytes.

I know that all objects store only the address of the value and that value is static, but I don't understand what I'm observing. What's going on?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918399/what-type-of-memory-heap-or-stack-string-constant-pool-in-java-gets-stored

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19402207/java-variable-placed-on-stack-or-heap

Comment: There is no such thing as a 'native object' in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique to measure object size you are using is just too crude: it gives you the size of only the `String` instance itself and not of all the other instances it refers to—the size of its entire *object graph*. Existing tools use the crude call you have used, combined with reflection to walk the rest of the object graph, calling the same method in each step.

Specifically, the `String` stores character data in a `char[]`, whose object size is the most relevant to the overall memory occupied by a `String`, for any longer string.

Comment: what are the tools you say?

Comment: Thanks I will try this tool, if i have 2 object that link to same object (String for example) the Heap-space of VM have only 1 object and 2 references right?

Comment: Yes, that would be it.